# Describing equivalence classes over the set of natural numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

So for this problem we are supposed to describe the equivalence class for the following relation. $x \thicksim y$ iff $x$ mod 2 = $y$ mod 2 *and* $x$ mod 4 = $y$ mod 4.

I am confused on what is meant when it says "describe" the equivalence class. What am I describing? Am I describing whether it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive? Or describing whether $x$ and $y$ are even or odd? I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

It probably means giving an expression for the equivalence class of $x\in \Bbb{Z}$ as a subset of $\Bbb{Z}$

Take $x,y \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $x\sim y$. In particular $x\equiv y \, mod \, 4$.

Conversely, if $x\equiv y \, mod \, 4$, there exists $q \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $4q=x-y$, from which we can deduce $x\equiv y \, mod \, 4$ and $x\equiv y \, mod \, 2$.

It follows that the equivalence class of $x$ under $\sim$ coincides with the equivalence class of $x$ modulo $4$, this is:

$$[x]=\left \{ y \in\mathbb{Z}: 4|(x-y) \ \right \}$$

Comment: I am uncertain where the $4q = x - y$ comes from. Could you explain? Also, you say this for $x = y$ $mod$ $4$, but does this work for $x$ $mod$ $4$ = $y$ $mod$ $4$?

Comment: @DietDrPepsi $4q=x-y$ follows from the definition of congruence modulo $4$. $a$ and $b$ are congruent modulo $4$ if and only if $4$ divide $b-a$. What do you mean exactly by $x mod 4 = y \mod 4$?